# Password protect wp-login.php

Tags: password

AS the title says, how do i password protect wp-login.php page?
So the user has to write a specific code to enter.
If possible there should be more than one code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess` to protect your wp-login.php. [The Codex describes how to do so.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks#Password_Protect_wp-login.php)

There are also some plugins which do that job for you, finding and choosing a good one is up to you.